# How to fix row to bottom of page in Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have worked with bootstrap i want to give last row of the page is given to the bottom of the page and that row is fixed and also in responsive size.

Comment: Please put a little more work into your question. Stack Overflow is meant to help other people with the same question, as well as you. I can barely make sense of it.

Comment: *I have worked with bootstrap i want to give last row of the page is given to the bottom of the page and that row is fixed and also in responsive size.* **Okay** show us what you did (html/css here in a snippet), so we might see where it fails. *fixed*  at bottom ? do you mean always in sight at window's bottom  or at bottom at the highest and past bottom if there is enough content to push it down ?

Answer (score 9):

This row class need to have those properties :

```
.fixed-row-bottom { position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="row fixed-row-bottom">My fixed row</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you post your code it is easier to answer. You will want to apply a fixed position to your element, like so:

```
.element {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```